# Why I get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: redis/clients/jedis/JedisClientConfig

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis

I have Spring Boot 2.7.12 application and I am accessing Redis via Spring Data Redis. I am getting an error " java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" while running my application:

```
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'redisKeyValueTemplate' while setting bean property 'keyValueOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redisKeyValueTemplate': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'redisKeyValueAdapter' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redisKeyValueAdapter': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'redisTemplate' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redisTemplate' defined in class path resource [ru/axothy/backdammon/registration/config/RedisConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate]: Factory method 'redisTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jedisConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [ru/axothy/backdammon/registration/config/RedisConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'jedisConnectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: redis/clients/jedis/JedisClientConfig
```

My RedisConfig class:

```
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {

    @Bean
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        JedisConnectionFactory jedisConFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
        jedisConFactory.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
        jedisConFactory.setPort(6379);
        return jedisConFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        return template;
    }
}
```

My build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.12'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
}

group = 'ru.axothy.backdammon'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "2021.0.7")
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-redis'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'

    implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap', version: '3.1.6'
    annotationProcessor "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client', version: '3.1.6'

    implementation group: 'org.keycloak', name: 'keycloak-admin-client', version: '21.1.1'

    implementation group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers', name: 'jersey-container-servlet-core', version: '3.1.2'
    implementation group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.core', name: 'jersey-server', version: '3.1.2'




}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I tried stackoverflow solutions: I removed jedis dependency from my build.gradle, but it didn't help. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to also add following dependency along with `spring-boot-starter-data-redis`.
The `JedisClientConfig.java` ,class belongs to `redis-clients:jedis`

```
implementation 'redis.clients:jedis'
```

Comment: No, it did not helped me. Same error

Comment: Same error, or any new error ? hope you did a `gradle clean build` & reloaded the project !!

Comment: Yes of course I builded and reloaded the project. But now I receive new error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: redis/clients/jedis/GeoUnit

Comment: I included Jedis 3 dependency instead of Jedis 4 and now problem is solved ! Thank you!